# Как перенести Microsoft Windows Server 2016 на VMWare ESXi 6.5?

Tags: сервер, администрирование, vmware, виртуализация

Подскажите как перенести физическую машину с Microsoft Windows Server 2016 в виртуальную среду VMWare ESXi 6.5?
VMWare vCentre Converter 6.1.1 не сильно хочет работать, при запуске выдает ошибку что не может определить учетные данные, а если руками указываешь, ругается что не может подключится по 443 порту. При этом порт в брандмауэре открыт, а netstat показывает что ничего нет на 443 порту. При попытке зайти telnet на порт, отрубает.

Полазил по форумам, кроме указания того что у Converter не заявлена поддержка WinServ 2016 ничего нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте совсем отключить firewall и антивирус(если есть).У вас сам сервис VMware vCenter Converter Server запущен в этот момент? Что в логах View Source Details, в журнале событий ОС?

Comment: firewall отключен и антивируса нет.
Не понял какие логи нужно посмотреть?

Comment: Служба VMware vCenter Converter Server запущена, вы проверили? В Windows logs (Application, System) есть ошибки относящиеся к Vmware?

Comment: служба запущенна, ошибок от vmware нет

Comment: Приложите скриншот  ошибки. Вы локальную машину конвертите или удаленную?

Comment: пытаюсь подключится к локально установленному серверу. Картинку прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: Если вам надо локальный сервер конвертнуть, то зачем вы Client-Server  инсталляцию выбрали, может какой компонент не доставили? Удалите Vmware convertor и установите заново, только выберете Local installation.

Comment: я не выбирал клиент серверную, я выбрал локальную. Это скриншот с того сервера который я хочу конвертнуть, на нем установлен сервер, агент и воркер

Comment: Если вам сложно переустановить vmware convertor в режиме local installation, то скачайте tcpview, запустите и покажите что у вас висит на 443 порту (https), в каком он состоянии и пришлите скрин